# Can't execute HTTP request to Youtube Data API from PHP

Tags: php, curl, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm writing a mass youtube link finder, which imports a list of titles from an array, generates an API url and the executes them with curl_multi.

However, curl returns blank data for each link. Links are fine as I can access to them correctly via Chrome.

file_get_contents() tried in another script with a url amongst those returns an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in Chrome.

Any help would be much appreciated,

EDIT: Code:

```
function getYTUrl($urls){

    $curls = array();
    $result = array();
    $arrjson = array();
    $mh = curl_multi_init();

    foreach ($urls as $key => $value) {

        echo $value;

        $curls[$key] = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curls[$key], CURLOPT_URL, $value);
        curl_setopt($curls[$key], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curls[$key], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curls[$key],CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curls[$key]);
    }
    $active = null;
    do{
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    } 
    while ($active);


    foreach ($urls as $key => $value) {
        $result[$key] = curl_multi_getcontent($curls[$value]);

        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $value);
    }

    curl_multi_close($mh);
}
```

Comment: You need to share your code. How can anyone help you find an error when there's nothing to look at?

Comment: @Novocaine Code added

Comment: I think the problem resides in the links being https.

Comment: I did not get your question, what you try to crawl, if it give you a blank page, or error, try to use it for only one url, And give a example, what type of url you send in your function